# How to insert Special Characters from PHP in Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle, insert, oracle11g, special-characters

I want to insert data with special character in oracle tables. 
My code is like this-:

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO sample(po_number , created_at , customer_firstname , customer_lastname , customer_email , 
shipping_description , ship_to_firstname, ship_to_lastname, ship_to_company, ship_to_street, ship_to_city, ship_to_country_id, ship_to_postcode, ship_to_telephone, increment_id) VALUES(".$result_str_order.")"; 


where $result_str_order = '100','21-Mar-2011','Sam','Right','sam.right@sasmple.com','Flight','Samy',
'RTR','SR INC','222,M.G.Bank's-Pipeline/Rd','Newyork','US','411230','999856230','20000507'
```

Now, in case of ship_to_street, I need to insert  **222,M.G.Bank's-Pipeline/Rd**
but it contains special character like ,',-,/ etc.so **how to insert special characters in oracle db?**

Comment: Are you asking about PHP or Oracle DB ? if it's Oracle then you need to to use `''` wherever you need a `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only character you need to escape is `'` (because you're using single quotes as string delimiters). So that's:

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO sample(po_number , created_at , customer_firstname , customer_lastname , customer_email , 
shipping_description , ship_to_firstname, ship_to_lastname, ship_to_company, ship_to_street, ship_to_city, ship_to_country_id, ship_to_postcode, ship_to_telephone, increment_id) VALUES(".$result_str_order.")"; 


where $result_str_order = '100','21-Mar-2011','Sam','Right','sam.right@sasmple.com','Flight','Samy',
'RTR','SR INC','222,M.G.Bank\'s-Pipeline/Rd','Newyork','US','411230','999856230','20000507'
```

Comment: So how to escape that or tell me exact ans. as I am unable to insert data in oracle?  What function shall I try for esacping  ' .

Comment: Just place a slash before it, `/'`, or insert another single quote before it. `''`

Comment: Slash won't work in Oracle. Nor will backslash. You need to double up on the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Replace method (on your variables, not the entire query) to duplicate single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue. I want to select this ■×× special character as a condition.

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM tablename
  WHERE table = '■××'
```

I used PHP MMSQL with oracle dB. To solved this, I used hex conversion RAWTOHEX

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE RAWTOHEX(table) = '81A1817E817E' --this is the hex for symbol above
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use quoted string like  **q'[$visitComment]'**  where $visitComment is a variable that contains a special character string.

Or you can bind externally
INSERT INTO sample(column) values (:columnval);
oci_bind_by_name($result, ':columnval',$string);

Where $result is $result = oci_parse($conn, $query);

Note:- This will work only for variable containing string.